# No permutation in $S_n$ can be expressed both as a product of an even number and an odd number of transpositions & Isomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> No permutation in $S_n$ can be expressed both as a product of an even number and an odd number of transpositions.

I have come across this theorem in Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*.
The author provides 2 proofs from different perspectives. I am interested in the proof where this is regarded from the point of view of Linear Algebra.
Here is roughly how it looks:

> We remarked that $S_A \cong S_B$ if $|A|=|B|$. We work with permutations of the $n$ rows of the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I_n$ insead of the numbers $1,2,\cdots ,n.$

The argument after that could be understood. The author used the fact that the determinant of an identity matrix where any of the two rows is interchanged for an even number of times will differ from an identity matrix where any of the two rows is interchanged for an odd number of times by a negative sign. So, no permutations is both the product of even and odd number of transpositions.

**First question**: My worry is about why we can choose to work with permutations of the $n$ rows of $I_n$ rather than the genuine one. Isn't it a bit like proving a general case from a specific case? I think isomorphism plays a role here. If yes, may I know how?

**Second question**: I have come across isomorphism when I was learning Linear Algebra. What is emphasised is its 'bijectiveness' and 'some kind of linearity'. But isomorphism is well-known for being a structure-preserving map. In case of groups, to what extent are the algebraic structures preserved by isomorphism? I know 'structures' here is a bit vague, but I am curious about what does not hold under isomorphism between two groups.

Also, can I say this: 'For two isomorphic groups, what is different is (only?) the letters used to represent the objects studied in the groups.'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "what does not hold under isomorphism between two groups" The names of the elements and the name of the operation. That's basically it. An isomorphism is a renaming of a group and its contents.